# Overloading a subroutine and function in Fortran

Tags: function, interface, fortran, overloading, subroutine

Is it possible to overload a subroutine and function using the interface blocks? So one can call a procedure via a function or subroutine. For example:

```
...
interface TestRoutine
      module procedure TestRoutine_fun
      module procedure TestRoutine_sub
end interface TestRoutine

Contains

function TestRoutine_fun(....) result(...)
...
end function TestRoutine_fun

subroutine TestRoutine_sub(...)
...
end subroutine TestRoutine_sub
...
```

When I tried to compile code similar to this I got the error:
Error: In generic interface 'TestRoutine' at (1) procedures must be either all SUBROUTINES or all FUNCTIONs.
Thanks in advance!

Answer (score 5):

No, not in the standard language.  The error message explains the situation correctly.

Answer (score 2):

You cannot overload a function with a subroutine. What you can do, though, is write a wrapper routine that calls the function (or the other way round). This way, you would at least save some code.